# In an RSA Lib I implemented myself, how do I convert the 2 parts of an RSA key to b64?

Tags: c, encryption, key, rsa

I'm using C for a small Crypto library I'm implementing. I've got n ( = p*q) and e ( > 1, co-prime of n). How do I convert these 2 numbers into one key?

Comment: Why do you need to?

Comment: Why do I need to convert the key to b64? Isn't that how it's done?

Comment: To do what? Storage of RSA keys is a rather broad topic.

Comment: To display them to the user

Comment: Why not base 10?

Comment: How would I go about combining them though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specifications for converting the key into a structure are in the [PKCS#1 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#appendix-C). This basically is just this ASN.1 structure:

```
RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
    modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
    publicExponent    INTEGER   -- e
}
```

This is then encoded using DER, the distinguished encoding rules for ASN.1. This is a binary encoding, which can of course be converted to base 64. Generally however it is not just converted to base 64, it will also be split into multiple lines and wrapped by a header line and footer line, giving you PEM. In this case the header should indicate an `RSA PUBLIC KEY`.

It you want higher compatibility the binary PKCS#1 structure is in turn preceeded by a descriptive wrapper used in X.509 certificates (those used within web browsers, among others). That structure is called `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` and the PEM wrapper will indicate type `PUBLIC KEY` - so without the RSA. That it **is** an RSA public key is already indicated by information within the binary structure.

But I guess you'd want to start with the relatively simple PKCS#1 structure and then expand on that. Try the old [A Layman's Guide to a Subset of ASN.1, BER, and DER](http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html) for more information.

---

I like standards, but you could also use a two-byte length indication for the modulus and the public exponent and then concatenate the two, as in:

```
<l_mod> <modulus> <l_exp> <pubexp>
```

Then you would still need to think of a specific way of encoding the integer values. I'd use unsigned big endian, that way the key size (*in bytes instead of bits*) is the `l_mod` value. Then you  can base64 the above. It's not standardized anywhere, but it is a lot easier to understand and program.